# Reloading non-focused forms for display changes in a windows form app.

Tags: .net, winforms, formatting, themes, reload

I have an application consisting of many different windows forms apps. Essentially, I'm trying to implement a Class called `ControlTheme`, which can control the color schemes for the entire app. When I change the color scheme in settings, I want all the currently open forms to reload and change their colors without having to relaunch the whole app. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have a method in each form called `Prep()` which gathers all the color information from the parent class `ControlTheme (this.ButtonColor = ControlTheme.ButtonColor)`, but even when this method is public I can't access it from the Settings page.

Comment: `I'm trying to implement a Class called ControlTheme` - Don't try to reinvent the wheel. winforms doesn't support theming. Use WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface you apply to every Form which has the Prep() method.

```
interface IThemable
{
    void Prep();
}
```

Then use Application.OpenWindows to tell you all the currently open windows in your app.

```
public void UpdateAllOpenWindows()
{
    foreach (var themableForm in Application.OpenForms.OfType<IThemable>())
    {
        themableForm.Prep();
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I managed to get it to work by simply raising an event, and adding delegates in the previous forms to listen for it.